# What is the correct way to perform a single blocking, synchronous receive with Pika?

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, pika

I would like to use Pika / RabbitMQ in a pattern similar to a standard socket: that is, set up the connection, then make blocking synchronous calls to receive a single message each time I'm ready to do more work.

## Option A: `basic_get`

The `basic_get` method of the `BlockingConnection` offers the ability to receive a message, but it returns immediately if there is no message available to receive. This is like a socket `recv` call with blocking disabled. I could use this approach with a timeout to poll continuously, but that's not efficient.

## Option B: `basic_consume`

The `basic_consume` method of `BlockingConnection` could do the job, but it has the strange requirement that I have `start_consuming()` somewhere else, in a thread by itself. Since my callers of my `receive` method are already expecting to block, waiting for a message, this seems like a waste of a thread.

Is it possible with Pika to do the equivalent of `socket.recv(blocking=True)`?

Answer (score 0):

Run Pika on its own thread and `basic_consume` with a prefetch value of 1 (if you really want a single message at a time). Insert messages into some sort of synchronized data structure on which your callers can block.

Be sure to acknowledge your messages correctly from other threads ([*example*](https://github.com/pika/pika/blob/0.12.0/examples/basic_consumer_threaded.py))

Answer (score 0):

Use the channel's basic_get method like in this example:

```
credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('username', 'password')
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost', credentials=credentials))
channel = connection.channel()

inmessage = channel.basic_get("your_queue_name", auto_ack=True)
```

inmessage is a tuple of 3 elements, element with index of 2 is your message's body.